# How to create an xarray from a sparse, denormalized table?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray, datashape

Say I have the following structured array:

```
import numpy as np

l, h, w = 6, 5, 5
dtype = [('a', int), ('b', '<U3'), ('data', (float, (h, w)))]
table = np.empty(l, dtype)
table['a'] = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
table['b'] = ['foo', 'bar'] * 3
table['data'] = np.random.rand(l, h, w)
```

My `data` has shape `(6, 5, 5)`.  But really, its shape is `(3, 2, 5, 5)`, but I just have columns `a` and `b` denormalized.

Is it possible to create an `xarray` `DataArray` directly from this shape `(6, 5, 5)` by providing columns `a` and `b` of length `6` and have `xarray` figure out the `(3, 2, 5, 5)` shape?  What would `coords` and `dims` be?

In reality, `table` is sparse and has many dimensions, and I'm trying to see if there's any `xarray` creation machinery I can lean on instead of reshaping `table` myself.